# Overflow issue with jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a menu panel for my jquery mobile website. Sadly I have a issue with overflow. What I want is that the menu comes in from the left and pushes the jquery mobile page to the right and partly outside the viewport.

This works all good on desktop browsers, but for some reason I get a horizonal scrollbar and I can 'scroll' away from the panel to the right(in to the actual page). I don't want this beheaviour ofcourse.

Tried various things with overflow and position but I can't seem to fix it.

I have created a stripped down version from my website on jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/uhucec/4

Any help would be realy appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a fix to this problem.

I have added a css class:

```
.ui-page-fixed
{
    position: fixed !important;
}
```

I apply this class to the current page when the panel is open, and remove it when the panel is closed.